# CLUSTERED Index seek taking too much cost

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a really big sql select query that I have to optimize because it takes 40 seconds.

Im using Sql Sentry Plan Explorer to do so and I found  that 2 "Clustered Index Seek operations" (in a 300k rows table) take nearly 60% of the whole process time.

My questions is:  **What could cause this "clustered index seek" to take so much time?** When I do a simple select on this table it takes only 2 seconds but this index seek takes like 24 seconds...

I also checked index fragmentation and its over 2%.

**NOTE: Sorry I dont post details but im not allowed to do so.**

Comment: No details, no answer possible. Why do you think it's the clustered index at fault? How many rows are you trying to read and how many columns? What does the query do? Is there a lot of contention on the table? Any other queries running concurrently? Is your query waiting to acquire locks held by others? What do you mean "simple select" anyway?

Comment: The plan explorer doesn't give you the exact costs, it gives you the `estimated costs` based on it's `statistics`. Meaning that it may be right about the 60% but it may not. But again, without a sample query is difficult to say.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The thing is that its a really complex query involving a huge number of diferent tables, views, rows and colums. The execution plan gives me that 60% of the time its only in this "index seek" operation. By simple select I mean "Select*from table" takes 2 seconds with 300k fields.

Comment: A really complex query *will* take a lot of time. A query that loads everything without filters on the other hand doesn't do anything expect send data across the network. You can't compare them

Comment: Use the Index Tuning Advisor to see whether some other indexes are needed. It isn't possible to help without any real information.

Comment: Also note that an inefficient query can hammer the only existing index on the table, where a better query could perform much faster

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos. And sorry again, Im not allowed to post any other info and I understand the problem that it is.

Comment: If you cannot post the real code and details then, however hard it may be, you need to try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Create tables that are *similar* to your real tables. Write scripts that populate the tables with nonsense data (but same volumes/distribution). Write a query that works against those tables and employs the same query patterns. Once it demonstrates the same problems, give us that. Or, in the process, you might find the essential difference between your real code and the sample you're creating and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At the first time you can try to update statistics.

For example so.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS ...
```

Or so.

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```